# Chromatic Number of Graph after Removing Vertex Proof

Tags: coloring

Show that χ(G − v) is either χ(G) or χ(G) − 1.
χ is the chromatic number of a graph, G is the graph, v is a vertex.

I am trying to prove this, using a 2 case method for the two options, but I cannot figure out how to prove either case.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Clearly $\chi (G) \geq \chi (G- v)$

**Hint:** Show that $ \chi (G) \leq \chi (G - v) + 1 $.

Hence, the result follows.